# Update a column of a table with some percentage of its value and then round it to nearest integer in SQL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Let's suppose I have a table `Employee` with three columns, `EID int`, `Salary int`, `Dept varchar`.

What I want to do is to increase the salary of every employee by 5% then increased value should be rounded to nearest integer like 2.7 should be stored as 3.

How could this be achieved in a SQL Sever query?

I tried this query but it's not working:

```
update Employee 
set Salary = ROUND(Salary * @1.05)
```

but instead it's displaying this error:

> The round function requires 2 to 3 arguments

Comment: have  u use ceil function

Comment: CEILING(Salary*@1.05) Returns the smallest integer greater than, or equal to, the specified numeric expression.

Comment: [See this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for the MSDN docs on the ROUND function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If salary is an `int`, then the value will automatically be truncated to fit.  So, just add 0.5:

```
update Employee
    set Salary = Salary * 1.05 + 0.5;
```

If you want to be very pedantic about the rounding rules:

```
update Employee
    set Salary = round(Salary * 1.05, 0);
```

I say pedantic, because "1.5" is rounded to 2, but "4.5" is rounded to 4.

Comment: I don't think it's pedantic to use `round()` in this case. I agree that the first solution is fine, but I think the second has greater code clarity.

Comment: wow amazing, Super Trick to solve this, i used your first method of adding 0.5